# How to access to specific item in Index list? (Blender 3.0)

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can i access to the specific Item in Index field?
In fact
I wanna turn some index numbers to zero and some to 1 to make a new selection list.

[image]

In fact i have this set of lines and i want to select some of these in between and remove some others

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more what you end goal is?

Comment: Thank you for your reply 
I have a set of curves that i want it to select every 3 of them interchangeably 
In fact i want to remove some of them in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can delete vertices like this:

[image]

but much easier as Gorgious helped me out here ([why to convert these points/vertices back to a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244107/why-to-convert-these-points-vertices-back-to-a-curve?noredirect=1#comment415623_244107)) use this:

[image]