# How can I selectively remove control points from a curve in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this GN setup:

[image]

I expected that if i unmute the mesh to curve node, that i got a curve...but i got...nothing.

Why don't i get a curve with half of the number of my resolution?

[image]

even the spreadsheet looks ok:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using the Resample Curve node to do that ?

Comment: It’s just an example, It would like to know how I can delete vertices in a curve 

Comment: Alright I figured so. :) What about the Delete Geometry node then ?

Comment: Btw to add my point of view to your question I think it's because a mesh's vertices are not spatially ordered (if a mesh contains only vertices, you can swap vertex indices without the mesh changing) whereas the order in which control points are defined in a spline define the shape of the spline.

Comment: yes, works with delete geometry as well. but how do i get my curve back? 

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDh9r.png ?

Comment: damn...that easy...thank you!! Now i now why you are gorgious, Gorgious! ;) If you wanna have 35 reputation...put that as an answer....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a Delete Geometry node to selectively remove control points from a curve geometry without having to convert it to and from mesh geometry.

You can add any field output in the Selection input of the Delete Geometry node, so long at it can be evaluated as a boolean (True, False) for each control point of the curve geometry.

A Value of True (or number > 0) will delete the control point, when a value of False (number <= 0) will keep it.

[image]

Comment: GORGIOUS!!!!!!!

Comment: @Chris hehe happy to help :) I changed the Q title to reflect more what you were trying to achieve hope you don't mind

Comment: I don’t mind. Thanks your quick answer!!!